# Can codegenerated CoreData entity classes be marked as `internal` instead of `public`?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am creating an iOS framework that internally uses CoreData. I've created a CoreData entity model to declare the entities. For each entity, I've declared that a corresponding class is created through codegen. Is there any way to mark these class definitions as `internal`, instead of `public` since I don't need apps using this framework to see these classes?

I know that I can manually create the class definitions, but this seems unnecessarily tedious to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to manually create them to be able to modify them, it’s as simple as that

Comment: By `codegen`, do you mean `SwiftGen`, if yes, I guess you used the default template, so instead copy/paste the content of the one you used, like https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen/blob/stable/Sources/SwiftGenCLI/templates/coredata/swift5.stencil and modify the accessModifier value `internal` to `public`. And when generating the file, use your custom template. or better, see the doc and use https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen/blob/stable/Documentation/templates/coredata/swift5.md `publicAccess` in the yaml file.